# Is there a way to send internal emails in Magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have a requirement to send internal emails in Magento i.e Admin user to Admin user. This is because we are running a small customer service team.

I also need to notify admin of failed orders etc and would like this to go straight to an internal inbox if possible??

I would be grateful for any extensions or Tutorials on how to do this if its possible with Magento.

Thanks is advance.

Comment: This is indirect solution: use one Gmail (or Google Apps) account shared by the team and put team member's labels and stars on email threads that need action. We do this & Google Apps hosts our domain's email.

Comment: @Chris K I really do need to integrate an internal email system as the current system has this functionality but we are moving to Magento. I need to provide this for customer service personnel

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do it within magento read this tutorial http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-advanced-transactional-email-templates as for failed orders you can use magento cron to check orders that failed and after successful notification add a flag saying that this order was checked and notification was sent so it want be taken for next cron run.

Regards,

Comment: Thankyou for your response which I have found very useful. However, the tutorial appears to be focused on transactional emails but I am looking for an internal system that will allow the Customer Service team to communicate with each other via the Admin... Thanks again!!

Comment: What I meant by this tutorial is that you can create you own module and send internal email using magento functionality :)

Comment: Ahh I see, I thought you misunderstood the question: Thankyou!